# JQuery: Changing option text based on yes/no input

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I have here are 3 select tags with options. What I would like to do is, for example, a user chooses "extra strength" option in the first select, they should see a yes/no prompt. If yes is selected, then all other select should have only "extra strength" options. If no is selected, then do nothing. Here is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<select id="bundle-option-49">
    <option value="1">Choose a selection...</option>
    <optgroup label="Regular Flavor">
        <option value="6455">Regular Double Extra +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6456">Regular Extra Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6457">Regular Full Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6458">Regular Light Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6459">Regular Nicotine Free +$0.00</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Menthol Flavor">
        <option value="6460">Menthol Double Extra +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6461">Menthol Extra Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6462">Menthol Full Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6463">Menthol Light Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6464">Menthol Nicotine Free +$0.00</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Vanilla Flavor">
        <option value="6460">Vanilla Double Extra +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6461">Vanilla Extra Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6462">Vanilla Full Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6463">Vanilla Light Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6464">Vanilla Nicotine Free +$0.00</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<div id="panel">
    <p>Would you like to set this strength for all selection?</p>
    <form action="">
        <input type=radio name="r" id=1>Yes
        <input type=radio name="r" id=0>No</form>
</div>
<select id="bundle-option-50">
    <option value="">Choose a selection...</option>
    <optgroup label="Regular Flavor">
        <option value="6520">Regular Double Extra +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6521">Regular Extra Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6522">Regular Full Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6523">Regular Light Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6524">Regular Nicotine Free +$0.00</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Menthol Flavor">
        <option value="6525">Menthol Double Extra +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6526">Menthol Extra Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6527">Menthol Full Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6528">Menthol Light Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6529">Menthol Nicotine Free +$0.00</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Vanilla Flavor">
        <option value="6460">Vanilla Double Extra +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6461">Vanilla Extra Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6462">Vanilla Full Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6463">Vanilla Light Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6464">Vanilla Nicotine Free +$0.00</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<select id="bundle-option-51">
    <option value="">Choose a selection...</option>
    <optgroup label="Regular Flavor">
        <option value="6520">Regular Double Extra +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6521">Regular Extra Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6522">Regular Full Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6523">Regular Light Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6524">Regular Nicotine Free +$0.00</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Menthol Flavor">
        <option value="6525">Menthol Double Extra +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6526">Menthol Extra Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6527">Menthol Full Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6528">Menthol Light Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6529">Menthol Nicotine Free +$0.00</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Vanilla Flavor">
        <option value="6460">Vanilla Double Extra +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6461">Vanilla Extra Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6462">Vanilla Full Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6463">Vanilla Light Strength +$0.00</option>
        <option value="6464">Vanilla Nicotine Free +$0.00</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bundle-option-49").one("change", function () {
        $("#panel").show("slow");
        $("#bundle-option-49").change(function () {
            var selected = (this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
            $("#1").click(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    //just to check if var is stored
                    //alert("You have selected" +selected);
                }
            });

        });

    });
});
```

CSS

```
#panel {
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

I am a newbie at JS. I would like to know if I am going in the right direction or what would be a better way to achieve this. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unable to understand...What u really want

Comment: Thanks for response. I have updated the question on what I would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this fiddle: [my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/EFL4g/1/)
and let me know if this is what you are wanting to do.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selected;
    var selectedClass;
    $("#bundle-option-49").on("change", function () {
        $("#panel").show("slow");        
            selected = (this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
            selectClass = ($(this).find('option:selected').attr('class'));
     $("#1").click(function () {
                if($('#1').is(':checked')) {                   
                    if(confirm("You have selected: " + selected))
                    {
                        $('option').hide();
                        $('option.'+selectClass).show();
                    }
                }
        });
    });
});
```

I updated the fiddle to handle the 'No' selection. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/EFL4g/7/)

Comment: This is Perfect! However, if I wanted to reset and show all original text on selecting "NO", I would just do the opposite like     $("#0").click(function () {
                if($('#0').is(':checked')) {                   
                    if(confirm("You have selected: " + selected))
                    {
                        $('option').show();
                        $('option.'+selectClass).hide();
                    }
                }
        });
Am I right? Sorry for asking again, still learning :)

Comment: yes, just you would not need the  `$('option.'+selectClass).hide();` part

Comment: @user3290309 Be sure to copy the HTML from the jsfiddle, I had assigned classes to each option for the show and hide functionality

Comment: I am trying the jsfiddle version that you posted. It doesn't work on that.

Comment: @user3290309 I updated the fiddle to use the disable attribute, however, in IE you cannot hide option tags in the select (chrome and firefox allow you too), if you want hide them in IE then you will need a more elaborate method that stores the options in an array or something, removes the ones not desired and then if you want to add them back just populate the option list from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Yees. I think you are in correct direction. I have created a jsfiddle with your above code.

http://jsfiddle.net/8dUN6/

Also did small change in your js function. Commented the event I think that is not needed.

```
$("#bundle-option-49").one("change", function () {
        $("#panel").show("slow");
        //$("#bundle-option-49").change(function () {
            var selected = (this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
            $("#1").change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    //just to check if var is stored
                    alert("You have selected" +selected);
                }
            });

        //});

    });
```

Comment: You are welcome. If it answers your question dont forget to mark it as answer. :)